# Python: faster operation for indexing

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, indexing

I have the following snippet that extracts indices of all unique values (hashable) in a sequence-like `data` with canonical indices and store them in a dictionary as lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict
idx_lists = defaultdict(list)
for idx, ele in enumerate(data):
    idx_lists[ele].append(idx)
```

This looks like to me a quite common use case. And it happens that 90% of the execution time of my code is spent in these few lines. This part is passed through over 10000 times during execution, and `len(data)` is around 50000 to 100000 each time this is run. Number of unique elements ranges from 50 to 150 roughly.

Is there a faster way, perhaps vectorized/c-extended (e.g. `numpy` or `pandas` methods), that achieves the same thing?

Many many thanks.

Comment: It seems unlikely that indexing is your bottleneck in these lines. Both indexing and appending are `O(1)` time operations, in fact.

Comment: @DSM Yes, `data` has canonical indices.

Comment: FWIW, I understand comprehensions are significantly faster than `for loop`s, so this might be something to benchmark. Not sure if giving up a `defaultdict` is something you can afford, though.

Comment: @FWIW Thanks. Will try. But I think comprehension forces memory allocation for `None`, which adds some unknown amount of overhead. Not sure worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this question to be pretty interesting and while I wasn't able to get a large improvement over the other proposed methods I did find a pure numpy method that was slightly faster than the other proposed methods.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

data = np.random.randint(0, 10**2, size=10**5)
series = pd.Series(data)

def get_values_and_indicies(input_data):
    input_data = np.asarray(input_data)
    sorted_indices = input_data.argsort() # Get the sorted indices
    # Get the sorted data so we can see where the values change
    sorted_data = input_data[sorted_indices]
    # Find the locations where the values change and include the first and last values
    run_endpoints = np.concatenate(([0], np.where(sorted_data[1:] != sorted_data[:-1])[0] + 1, [len(input_data)]))
    # Get the unique values themselves
    unique_vals = sorted_data[run_endpoints[:-1]]
    # Return the unique values along with the indices associated with that value
    return {unique_vals[i]: sorted_indices[run_endpoints[i]:run_endpoints[i + 1]].tolist() for i in range(num_values)}


def by_dd(input_data):
    idx_lists = defaultdict(list)
    for idx, ele in enumerate(input_data):
        idx_lists[ele].append(idx)
    return idx_lists

def by_pand1(input_data):
    idx_lists = defaultdict(list)
    return {k: v.tolist() for k,v in series.groupby(input_data).indices.items()}

def by_pand2(input_data):
    return series.groupby(input_data).indices

def data_to_idxlists(input_data):
    u, ixs = np.unique(input_data, return_inverse=True)
    return {u: np.nonzero(ixs==i) for i, u in enumerate(u)}

def data_to_idxlists_unique(input_data):
    sorting_ixs = np.argsort(input_data)
    uniques, unique_indices = np.unique(input_data[sorting_ixs], return_index = True)
    return {u: sorting_ixs[start:stop] for u, start, stop in zip(uniques, unique_indices, list(unique_indices[1:])+[None])}
```

The resulting timings were (from fastest to slowest):

```
>>> %timeit get_values_and_indicies(data)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.25 ms per loop
>>> %timeit by_pand2(series)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.22 ms per loop
>>> %timeit data_to_idxlists_unique(data)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.23 ms per loop
>>> %timeit by_pand1(series)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.2 ms per loop
>>> %timeit data_to_idxlists(data)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.5 ms per loop
>>> %timeit by_dd(data)
10 loops, best of 3: 21.4 ms per loop
```

and it should be noted that unlike by_pand2 it results a dict of lists as given in the example. If you would prefer to return a `defaultdict` you can simply change the last time to `return defaultdict(list, ((unique_vals[i], sorted_indices[run_endpoints[i]:run_endpoints[i + 1]].tolist()) for i in range(num_values)))` which increased the overall timing in my tests to 4.4 ms.

Lastly, I should note that these timing are data sensitive.  When I used only 10 different values I got:

1. get_values_and_indicies: 4.34 ms per loop
2. data_to_idxlists_unique: 4.42 ms per loop
3. by_pand2: 4.83 ms per loop
4. data_to_idxlists: 6.09 ms per loop
5. by_pand1: 9.39 ms per loop
6. by_dd: 22.4 ms per loop

while if I used 10,000 different values I got:

1. get_values_and_indicies: 7.00 ms per loop
2. data_to_idxlists_unique: 14.8 ms per loop
3. by_dd: 29.8 ms per loop
4. by_pand2: 47.7 ms per loop
5. by_pand1: 67.3 ms per loop
6. data_to_idxlists: 869 ms per loop

Answer (score 5):

Not as impressive as I hoped for originally (there's still a fair bit of pure Python in the groupby code path), but you might be able to cut the time down by a factor of 2-4, depending on how much you care about the exact final types involved:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

def by_dd(data):
    idx_lists = defaultdict(list)
    for idx, ele in enumerate(data):
        idx_lists[ele].append(idx)
    return idx_lists

def by_pand1(data):
    return {k: v.tolist() for k,v in data.groupby(data.values).indices.items()}

def by_pand2(data):
    return data.groupby(data.values).indices

data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=10**5))
```

gives me

```
>>> %timeit by_dd(data)
10 loops, best of 3: 42.9 ms per loop
>>> %timeit by_pand1(data)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.2 ms per loop
>>> %timeit by_pand2(data)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Though it's not the perfect solution (it's O(NlogN) instead of O(N)), a much faster, vectorized way to do it is:

```
def data_to_idxlists(data):
    sorting_ixs = np.argsort(data)
    uniques, unique_indices = np.unique(data[sorting_ixs], return_index = True)
    return {u: sorting_ixs[start:stop] for u, start, stop in zip(uniques, unique_indices, list(unique_indices[1:])+[None])}
```

Another solution that is O(N*U), (where U is the number of unique groups):

```
def data_to_idxlists(data):
    u, ixs = np.unique(data, return_inverse=True)
    return {u: np.nonzero(ixs==i) for i, u in enumerate(u)}
```